# Mounting SD Card on windows 7

Tags: windows, drivers

i have a micro sd card (class 10) i bought.
i tried using it with my camera and it worked, also my phone.

but if i connect my camera to my pc (windows 7) it won't work:
it creates a new drive(Removeable Disk) but if i double click it says please insert disk.

so i tried using the camera with a different card i had and it worked.

its just the combination of the sdcard + pc

how can i fix this?

Comment: What was the "file system" that the device formatted the card with? Where was the card originally formatted? and what file system does it prefer to format a card with?

Comment: i cant see it on pc, only on android. but its either fat32 or exfat

Comment: i double checked. its fat32

Comment: I wonder if it is a partitioning issue? windows does not handle partitions on flash cards/sticks well? (which does not explain why there is a problem when connecting with the camera) If there are tricks used in the card or the method of formatting/layout on the card that windows goes brain dead on.  What is the size of the card?

Comment: 32gb.
i now tried formatting it on my phone using an app. still no change

Answer (score 1):

You access the camera using USB, right? Try mounting the card externally using a card reader.

Comment: it doesn't work as a "mass storage". but i can put it on my phone and connect it as a "media device" which works but is a lot of effort